# Gaussian blur gets pixelated when I copy, paste, and shrink image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, scale

I am creating a set of comic strips. I create each panel in its own Illustrator file. Then, when it's time to assemble the panels into one strip, I copy, paste, and shrink the images so that multiple panels are on one page. Some of these panels have a Gaussian blur. When I do the rescaling when assembling the comic strip, the blur looks not like a blur but pixelated. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is the effect getting scaled down as well (I suppose yes)? How small is the new object size? How small is the new blur effect?

Comment: Yep, it's smaller. I'd estimate that the new image is roughly 1/4 of its original size. What do you mean by "how small is the new blur effect"? If this helps, I will say the original effect is 3 pixels. After shrinking it is .7 pixels. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the same resolution in Document Raster Effects Settings? Sounds like you could have lower resolution in the document you paste in to. Try change that in that case.

Go to Effects > Document Raster Effects Settings and change the resolution to 300 ppi (or whatever default resolution you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

If your final image is really tiny then it will look like pixels... You need a larger image to get higher quality, there's no way around it.

If you have a 300 x 300px image and you shrink it to 64 x 64px, *it will* look pixelated. There are not enough pixels to contain the same amount of detail as the larger version.

Comment: Why? I'd think if anything it would be the other way around. And since it's a vector graphic...???

Comment: @julie1013 Isn't the gaussian blur effect pixel-based?

Comment: I don't know, apparently... :( Even if it is pixel-based, why does making it SMALLER pixelate it? I would think making it BIGGER would.